# What can a level 10-12 Necromancer do and bring to a party?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, necromancy

What can a level 10-12 Necromancer do and bring (by himself) to a party?

Just asking in general because I'm new to D&D and want to see my necromancer fight hordes of goblins and/or other monsters but also want to know his limits and capabilities.

Comment: The [[tag:dungeons-and-dragons]] tag is used for the game’s history across its many, many editions; for a question like this, we need to know which one you’re playing. So please replace [[tag:dungeons-and-dragons]] with the tag for the edition you’re playing, e.g. [[tag:dnd-5e]] for the latest one.

Comment: Furthermore, you will need to clarify what research you've already done and narrow what matters you're unclear on. My first response is to ask if you've read the rulebook, because if you're talking about any edition, the options at levels 10-12 are so numerous that it's too broad to practically answer. I would recommend detailing what your party is comprised of, whether you seek to deal damage, control the field, buff the party, etc. and if the utilization of undead is central to your goal (you did describe yourself as a necromancer, not simply a wizard or a cleric).

Comment: @Pyrotechnical A broad overview of what the necromancer wizard’s strengths and weaknesses are at that level is entirely reasonable as a question, and while it would be far too broad to discuss every option, answerers can also paint with a broad brush. This question definitely does not require answers that are too broad.